# How to count the number of files and folders in /usr/bin

Tags: command-line

I have to  use the combination of **ls** and **wc** to count the numbers of files and folders in /usr/bin, clearly there is  files and folders in it but when i do this command : `ls /usr/bin/ | wc /usr/bin/`

The out put is 0 :

```
wc: /usr/bin/: Is a directory
      0       0       0 /usr/bin/
```

Clearly from this screenshot, the answer shouldn't be 0 :

[image]

Any clues? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not using the output that you get from your `ls` command in the `wc`. Instead of doing `ls /usr/bin/ | wc /usr/bin/` you should use `ls /usr/bin/ | wc` . For example, for one of my folders:

```
ls Temp/ | wc
    16      16     292
```

Otherwise, `wc` tries to work with `/usr/bin/` directly, which it is not capable of(it supports only files, as your error clearly states)

Comment: ahhh thanks, just to be sure the last number is all the files included inside the folders we see in /usr/bin/ right ? Thanks again im new to linux !

Comment: @codetime Not quite. If you wish to recursively look into other directories and calculate their files as well, use `ls -R` instead of `ls`(if you use `ls` only the parent directory and files inside of it are listed). The rest of the command stays the same. Also, for `wc` the output format is `lines words bytes`. You are looking for lines, as `ls` will list each filename line by line

Answer (score 1):

if you are specific about to count only directories then use

```
[student@localhost ~]$ ls -d -- */ | wc
      8       8      75
```

it will count the directories from the current working directory, as in the above case it counts the total directories of the student's home directory which was 8:

```
[student@localhost ~]$ ls -d -- */
Desktop/  Documents/  Downloads/  Music/  Pictures/  Public/  Templates/  Videos/
```

if you want to count all then as above said by Alex use

```
ls /usr/bin | wc
```